# UnexpectedValueException Could not parse version constraint ^1.0.2: Invalid version string "^1.0.2"

Tags: composer-php, satis

Composer gives the following error:

```
Could not load package phpspec/prophecy in http://packagist.org: [UnexpectedValueException] Could not parse version constraint ^1.0.2: Invalid version string "^1.0.2"
```

Answer (score 6):

Composer added the ability to use the caret operator in early December 2014. Updating Composer will eliminate this problem - which is quite common because everyone uses PHPUnit, and PHPUnit started using this operator in late January 2015.

Answer (score -2):

Found this post on github:
https://github.com/phpspec/prophecy/commit/f802af851cc983d0ed074d29cba14af6766a24b1

Which says:

> Update your composer version.
>
> I've just checked https://github.com/composer/satis and satis is infact using a version of composer that supports this new syntax, so you must be using an old version of satis.

– GrahamCampbell added a note 19 days ago

Try updating composer (and satis if you use it)

---

Additionally this has been reported here: https://github.com/composer/satis/issues/200